# How to build javascript ad rotator?

Tags: javascript

I have a blog aggregator with many contributing blogs. I would like to distribute a snippet of javascript that contributors could place on their blogs.  After placement the javascript would load a link and image that would point to the aggregator -- very much the same way that Google Adsense works but on a simpler and smaller scale.

Can anyone provide or direct me to some sample code?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic idea is to give your users

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourdomain.com/advert.js"></script>
```

and inside your advert.js file you could have the link to your ads. this file can be generated using php as well. eg.

```
document.write('<a href="http://yourdomain.com"><img src="http://yourdomain.com/ag.png" alt="advert" /></a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you: http://www.winnershtriangle.com/w/Products.JavaScriptBannerAdRotator.asp